# Is the dos batch-processsing have zip incremental backup?

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I know there is a

```
tar -g snapshot -zcf target.tar.gz backupfile
```

in linux.
Now I want to acheieve this in windows?
so is there a zip command in windows can acheive the incremental backup based on complete zip file?

I know the zip command in windows can acheive incremental backup through the -u option

[image]

the example is like as

```
zip -r d:\backup.zip  d:\backupdir
```

after some files changed in d:\backupdir,I can through

```
zip -ru d:\backup.zip d:\backupdir
```

to add the changed file to backup.zip

but I want to make the diffrence file compressed in a new zip file rather than add the old zip file.

Comment: I am a fool.the picture shows -t mmddyyyy can acheive this.

Comment: but the -t mmddyyyy can only add the file those their modify time  big than mmddyyyy.I want to add the file those their modify time or create time big than mmddyyyy

Comment: `zip --dif full_backup.zip -r somedir --out diff.zip`.Hope this question can help somebody